# Theme css selectors with React JS/Polymer

Tags: css, css-selectors, polymer, reactjs, shadow-dom

I'm working with a project that uses ReactJS and I'd like to modify the theme. I'm running into an issue writing the css selectors for my theme styles. <s>It looks like reactjs uses some shadow dom which breaks css selectors across components.</s> It looks like polymer uses shadow dom which breaks css selectors across components (by design).

```
<div id="root" class="light-theme">
  <style>
    .light-theme .bg-theme {
      background-color: white;
    }
  </style>
  <parent-element>
    <child-element class="bg-theme">
    </child-element>
  </parent-element>
</div>
```

I'd like for the `child-element`'s background color to change based on the class I add to the root element.

<s>PS - The project also uses polymer.js, could this be the source of the shadow dom?</s>

**Update**

After some research, and see one of the answers below, polymer is indeed the cause of the shadow dom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Brandon's link I found the answer on this site:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/

> The `/deep/` combinator is similar to `::shadow`, but more powerful. It completely ignores all shadow boundaries and crosses into any number of shadow trees. Put simply, `/deep/` allows you to drill into an element's guts and target any node.

```
<div id="root" class="light-theme">
  <style>
    .light-theme /deep/ .bg-theme {
      background-color: white;
    }
  </style>
  <parent-element>
    <child-element class="bg-theme">
    </child-element>
  </parent-element>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

React doesn't do any shadow DOM specific stuff; Polymer most certainly does. They have [a documentation page on styling](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html).

> This document outlines those features, including [...] the specifics on how the the Shadow DOM polyfill applies styles

Comment: Thanks for the link, I found the answer from there