# Polymer share styles across elements

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, shadow-dom

I need to share styles across multiple Polymer elements. Is it acceptable to create a "styles.html" file and then import that into my different elements or would this start to have performance implications as the app grows? I know for 0.5 there was a core-styles but it kind of seems unnecessary if imports will work just as well.

styles.html

```
<style>
  button {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
```

my-button.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../styles/main-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="../behaviors/mixins.html">

<dom-module id="my-button">
  <template>
    <button>{{text}}</button>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-button',
    behaviors: [ButtonBehavior]
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Styling guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html)? You could propagate common styles down the DOM tree. This seems like a 'clean' way to use as it propagates automatically. You are not bound to a file (with a specific name) and styles are applied automatically if someone forgets to import the style file or just wants to use the default scheme.

Comment: I did look at the default guide. I guess my question overall is just if the method of importing them with imports would have performance implication or if it is just a style preference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298500/polymer-import-theme-file-with-host-in-styles-has-no-affect

Answer (score 7):

As suggested in [discussion](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489954#c12) on issue logged in chromium to deprecate /deep/ and ::shadow selectors:

> say your common styles are in a file called
>
> common-style.css
>
> In your component have a style tag that is like this
>
> @import url( '/common-style.css' );
>
> This inverts the control : instead of broadcasting your styles for
>   anyone to use, style consumers must know which styles they want and
>   actively request them, which helps avoid conflicts. With browser
>   caching, there's essentially no penalty to so many imports, in fact it
>   is likely faster than cascading the styles through multiple shadow
>   trees using piercers.

You can create a style.css and import it in your components by putting a css @import in your template.
There won't be multiple network calls, since browser is going to cache it when your first component *loads* and for subsequent components it will picked from cache.

We have been using webcomponents in our production apps for a while now using this technique since /deep/ has been deprecated and there has not been any signification performance difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Polymer's shared styles. Create a document with your styles:

```
<dom-module id="shared-styles">
  <template>
    <style>
      /* Your styles */
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

And then import this to your elements and in their definitions add `include="shared-styles"` to the `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Share styles by creating a `dom-module` for them, just like other custom elements. To include the shared styles in a custom element, use `<style include="style-module-name">`. Full example below.

**shared-styles.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="shared-styles">
  <template>
    <style>
      /* CSS goes here */
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

**some-element.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<dom-module id="some-element">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      /* Element specific styles go here */
    </style>
    <!-- HTML goes here -->
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'some-element',
      properties: {
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Polymer 1.1, the polymer project authors recommend creating and importing a style module to address this issue.

> To share style declarations between elements, you can package a set of style declarations inside a  element. In this section, a  holding styles is called a style module for convenience.
>
> A style module declares a named set of style rules that can be imported into an element definition, or into a custom-style element.

See more: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules