# Is there a way to use css in ng-content inside an Angular2 component?

Tags: css, angular, styles, angular2-ngcontent

I tried to include css for children element included in a component via **`ng-content`**. It seems to be not implemented yet in Angular 2 or maybe someone has got a solution except to put css in a general stylesheet ?

**`app.component.ts`**

```
<comp-parent>
  <comp-child></comp-child>
</comp-parent>
```

**`compParent.component.html`**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**`compParent.component.css`**

```
.wrapper > comp-child {
   margin-right: 5px; <-- Not applied !!!
}
```

Comment: <comp-child> is your component. Place the HTML element instead. For example - your <comp-child> will be replaced by the template which has another component <ng-component>. Use the HTML element that will actually render in the DOM.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `/deep/` (deprecated) or `>>>` or `::ng-deep` selector:

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

E.g.:

```
.wrapper ::ng-deep comp-child { ... }
```

Note that `>>>` seems to not work for projects based on angular-cli.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be work if you add :host to use /deep/.

Comment: Note that /deep/ is in deprecation status https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741722/whats-the-substitute-for-shadow-and-deep

Answer (score -1):

Apply classes to the html which is going to be rendered.

```
 app.component.ts
  <comp-parent>
    <comp-child></comp-child>
  </comp-parent> 

@Component({

    selector: 'comp-parent',
    template: `
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
        `          
})
export class CompParent { }   

@Component({
selector: 'comp-child',
template: `
    <div class="comp-child">
        <div>
        </div>
    </div> `,
})

export class CompChild {}


/// In styles.css
.wrapper .comp-child {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

This worked for me in my project.

Comment: "... except to put css in a general stylesheet ?" ;-) . Of course, that works in styles.css.