# How to add mixin for height in mwc textfield?

Tags: html, web-component, lit-element, polymer-3.x, lit-html

I am using polymer 3 and lit-element(2.2.1). The version of mwc-textfield is 0.13.0. I have read the documentations related to this version.In this [documentation](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field/), I have found that we can add mixin for height. I had tried several ways but did not succeed. May be the syntax I am using is wrong. I want to decrease the height of my text field. This is my text field

```
<mwc-textfield id="textBox" .type="text" .value=${this.title} .placeholder='' minLength="10" maxLength="256"></mwc-textfield>
```

and my css

```
 #textBox{
  text-transform: none;
   --mdc-theme-primary: transparent;
   --mdc-text-field-fill-color: #fff;
   --mdc-text-field-hover-line-color: #f5f5f5;
   --mwc-text-width: 100%;
   width:100%;
 }
```

The default css applied is

```
:host(:not([disabled])) .mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--outlined) {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) {
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
.mdc-text-field {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.mdc-text-field {
    height: 56px;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    will-change: opacity, transform, color;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.mdc-text-field {
    --mdc-ripple-fg-size:  0;
    --mdc-ripple-left:  0;
    --mdc-ripple-top:  0;
    --mdc-ripple-fg-scale:  1;
    --mdc-ripple-fg-translate-end:  0;
    --mdc-ripple-fg-translate-start:  0;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
user agent stylesheet
label {
    cursor: default;
}
<style>
#textfield {
    width: var(--text-field-width,80%);
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -12px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    --mwc-text-width: 100%;
}
<style>
mwc-textfield {
    --mdc-theme-primary: transparent;
    --mdc-text-field-ink-color: black;
    --mdc-text-field-fill-color: transparent;
    --mdc-text-field-disabled-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

The default height applied to the text field is 56px. What I have tried is

```
 #textbox.mdc-text-field--height{
    height:45px;
    }
```

and

```
#textbox.mdc-text-field--height('45px');
```

and also added mixin in the node modules file as **height:var(--mdc-text-field-height,56px);**
and used in css as

```
#textBox{
--mdc-text-field-height:45px;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Material design components vs Material web components**

> I have read the documentations related to this version. In this [documentation](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field/), I have found that we can add mixin for height.

The first thing to note here is that there are two different libraries of material components: the one you are referring to is MDC (Material Design Components, distributed on npm as `@material/<component>`) which is a SASS+JS implementation of Material components. The other one is MWC (Material Web Components, distributed as `@material/mwc-<component>`), a collection of actual [WebComponents](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components) based on the former library. So keep in mind that the documentation refers to the MDC counterpart of the MWC component you're actually using (`<mwc-textfield>`).

**Styling from the outside**

What you're trying to do here

```css
#textbox.mdc-text-field--height {
  height: 45px;
}
```

doesn't work mainly because selecting inside a custom element's shadow root is not possible (at least, [not anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741722/whats-the-substitute-for-shadow-and-deep)); also, the element responsible for the height is the `<label>`, whose class is `.mdc-text-field`.

**The querySelector way**

The quickest way to change the height that comes to my mind is this:

```js
import { LitElement, html, property, customElement, css, query } from 'lit-element';
import '@material/mwc-textfield';

@customElement('my-component')
export class MyComponent extends LitElement {
  // Select the text field
  @query('mwc-textfield') textField;

  async firstUpdated() {
    // Wait for its dom to be ready
    await this.textField.updateComplete;
    // Programmatically select the label
    // and change the height
    this.textField
    .shadowRoot
    .querySelector('.mdc-text-field')
    .style
    .height = '45px';
  }

  render() {
    return html`<mwc-textfield></mwc-textfield>`;
  }
}
```

however I would *really* not recommend it: performance and elegance aside, it'll probably break some of `mwc-textfield` features such as the floating label.

**The extension way**

You can also enforce the height by extending `TextField` and overriding the styles:

```js
import {LitElement, html, customElement, css} from 'lit-element';
import {TextField} from '@material/mwc-textfield/mwc-textfield';

@customElement('my-textfield')
export class MyTextfield extends TextField {
  static styles = [TextField.styles, css`
    .mdc-text-field {
      height: 45px;
    }
  `];
}

// Then use <my-textfield> instead of <mwc-textfield>
```

but again, like the above, use at your own risk...

**Using the mixin**

I guess for now the only way of using the `height` mixin is building a customised version of TextField which more or less goes like this:

- clone the [mwc repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components) (yeah, it's a monorepo so you get all the other components as well, but I'm pretty sure you can delete all the ones not imported by mwc-textfield)
- npm install
- in `packages/mwc-textfield/src/mwc-textfield.scss` use the mixin:

  ```
  @include mixins.height(45px);
  ```

  probably around [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/blob/master/packages/textfield/src/mwc-textfield.scss#L50)
- npm run build
- copy the mwc-textfield folder and paste it in your project (delete the source files, [npm pack](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/pack.html) may be handy for this), then change the imports from `@material/mwc-textfield` to `./path/to/custom-textfield`

Certainly too much work for changing a height... The good news is MWC is still in development and it cannot be excluded that they'll add a CSS custom property or some other way to customise the height. Also, the new [density](https://material.io/design/layout/applying-density.html) concepts are being implemented in MWC (sadly not yet in TextField), which could be just what you need.

There is also an open [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/issues/975) about this, let's see what they say

Comment: The thing that i dont want to extend as custom textfield is because When there is a upgrade in webcomponents, then I have to define my own custom textfield again and again.So I want to use the original text field by using the given mixins.

Comment: I see... But let me point out that the mixin you're mentioning is a sass mixin usable in the context of [uncompiled MDC components](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/#using-mdc-web-with-sass-and-es2015). In MWC there is no such thing: they come with precompiled CSS; sorry if I didn't make this clear in my answer. Anyway, if you don't want to set the height using `querySelector`, have you considered switching to the MDC version?

Comment: Ok I got that in your answer, but I am seeing for other alternatives in MWC rather than switching to MDC

Comment: Thank you @Umbo, The extension part worked for me with small changes.