# How to replace ::shadow without modifying the third-party element

Tags: css, polymer-1.0, shadow-dom

I'm looking for a way to replace `::shadow` now that it is gone. I've found two topics about it on this website, but both imply to modify the shadow element.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699350/shadow-piercing-descendant-combinator-deep-including-shadow-pseudo-el?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741722/whats-the-substitute-for-shadow-and-deep)

But the point of Web Components is to be able to import any element we found on the Internet in our webpage / app. So, it means that I don't wanna modify anything on these "third parties elements", because there are sources, and if I modify them, it will be overwritten when I later update them.

So, imagine that I download on `webcomponents.org` an element that creates some sort of button, but I need to change the color of this button because it doesn't fit the style of my page/app. The element creator has put no variable in his CSS, no `@apply` rule, no imports, nothing. Just the polymer element itself, working properly.

How can I do this without modifying the element's source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to style it imperatively. Get a reference to the element, use the DOM API on it to query its shadow DOM for the inner element you want to modify, then set the `style` property of that reference.

For example, the [`<gold-cc-cvc-input>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/gold-cc-cvc-input) currently has no extension points for styling its credit card icon.

1. Right-click the icon in Chrome, and inspect it in DevTools. We see the icon has an `id` of "icon".
2. Get a reference to `<gold-cc-cvc-input id="cvc">`, and set the `style` of the "icon" element. Here, we're using Polymer's [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding) to get a reference to the `<gold-cc-cvc-input>` by its ID (i.e., `this.$.cvc`) and then a reference to the inner "icon" element (i.e., `this.$.cvc.$.icon`).

   ```
   this.$.cvc.$.icon.style.border = 'solid 2px blue';
   ```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    attached: function() {
      this.$.cvc.$.icon.style.border = 'solid 2px blue';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="gold-cc-cvc-input/gold-cc-cvc-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <gold-cc-cvc-input id="cvc"></gold-cc-cvc-input>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/apGjpz?editors=1010)

Comment: It works! Thanks (again) tony! Though the problem of proceeding this way is that we cannot use css variable :/

Comment: @SKMTH No problem. You can actually use [`this.getComputedStyleValue('--my-custom-style')`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-getComputedStyleValue) in a Polymer element to imperatively query a CSS variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can style it from your container element, just look at the structure of the 3rd parties element. E.g.`<paper-card>` is the element you whant to style. paper-cards have divs inside:
shady DOM (Polymer 1.*)

```
<style>
  paper-card div{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 30px;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-card/paper-card.html">
  <style>
    .thirdPartEl div{
      background-color: red;
      padding: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <paper-card heading="I'm unstyled 3rd parties element"></paper-card>
  <paper-card class="thirdPartEl" heading="I'm styled 3rd parties element"></paper-card>
</body>
```

shadow DOM (Polymer 2.0)
for styling element from outside just use tag name as selector

```
<style>
  paper-card{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 30px;
  }
</style>
```

but if you want to style internals, you need custom CSS properties. if these aren't set, you can style them imho only via js at the moment

Comment: The caveat is this doesn't work with shadow DOM. Your solution requires shady DOM (the default in Polymer 1.x, but not the default in 2.x). ([demo](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VPdLeR?editors=1000))