# How to use global css styles in shadow dom

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

Shadow `dom` encapsulate css styles, selectors don't cross the shadow boundary.

**Question:** How to use global common css styles in shadow dom?
(suppose there are some common css styles which will be used across all pages (e.g.: font-family, h1, h2, clear, reset ...), how to make it works in shadow dom?)

Answer (score 8):

I've just struggled with the same problem as an original issue, namely: defining **once** some global rule for, say, `<h3>` element and benefit from that within any/many `ShadowDOM`s.

No, `css-variables` are **not** suited well for this thing, since even if I've defined once, say, `font` and `color` variables for `<h3>`, I'll still need to go over each and every shadowed stylesheet and add a CSS rule consuming them.

At the point of writing this (yes, we are 2019 now) **the shortest standardized** solution is indeed **importing** some global common CSS. Works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and Anaheim (Edge on Chromium).

It still requires to add an `@import` rule in each and every component, so still costy (from coding/maintenance POV, the stylesheet fetched only once), but that's the lowest price we can pay now.

Comment: TIL what I've always heard referred to as Edgium is officially branded Anaheim

Answer (score 5):

**It is 2022**

ShadowDOM is styled by:

- `<style>` within shadowDOM
- Inheritable styles
  https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/
- (cascading) CSS properties
- shadowParts (and Themes)
  https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/
- `<slot>` are **reflected**, they are NOT styled by the shadowDOM, but by its container.
  See: [::slotted content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)
- (feb 2022) Constructible StyleSheets is still a Chromium only party
  https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_cssstylesheet_cssstylesheet
- your custom directive

Answer (score 3):

**Note: As of 2023, this answer may be outdated. Please see other answers for updated information.**

---

Some solutions:

- CSS variables:

1. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/
2. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/css-variables-why-should-you-care?hl=en
3. http://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/chrome-49-beta-css-custom-properties.html

- `:host-context`:
  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/
- Also, I haven't tested, but someone suggested `@import url('/common-style.css');`, here: [Polymer share styles across elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829019/polymer-share-styles-across-elements/32941101#32941101)

Please note, one of the articles listed above was also pointed out by Amid. By the time that article was written, Chrome had no CSS variables. But now it already works natively with the recently launched Google Chrome 49.

Comment: Thanks! So CSS variable, :host-context, ::shadow(deprecated) are the answers for this question. While, the context for this question is: when I'm trying angular2, it introduces shadow DOM for components. My concern is, if we encapsulate the whole page into one nested shadow DOM tree, above things may not be a solution for css sharing, imagine we involve in bootstrap, how do we use it in shadow DOM?

Comment: I see how to use CSS variables, but it feels awkward not to be able to override browser built-in styles globally. The docs and specs seem to change again and again. There's changin @apply syntax, deprecated ::shadow, experimental ::theme and so on. Anybody with a sustainable solution?

Answer (score 3):

Non of the provided links work for me in Chrome 66 (as of 2018) so I ended up with this to customize custom element from outside:

```
<custom-element tabindex=10>
  <style>
    :host div {
      --color: red;
    }
  </style>
</custom-element>

class Element extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

        var user_style = shadow.host.innerHTML.match(/<style>([\s\S]*?)<\/style>/);
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.innerHTML = `
            :host div {
                color: var(--color, #aaa);
             }
        ` + user_style ? user_style[1] : '';    

        shadow.appendChild(style);
        shadow.host.querySelector('style').remove();
    }
}

customElements.define(
  "custom-element",
  Element
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Define styles in a base element and have all elements that need the style inherit from that base element.

With lit, something like this

```js
export class AppComponentBase extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`
:host {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 21px;
}
`;
}
```

And then in stead of inheriting from `LitElement`, make all components in your application inherit from `AppComponentBase` like this:

```js
export class HomeRouteComponent extends AppComponentBase {

    render() {
        return html`
<h1>Home</h1>
<p>
    Welcome to my website
</p>
`;
    }
}
```

You can also add or some styles

```js
export class HomeRouteComponent extends AppComponentBase {
    static styles = [super.styles, css`
h1 {
    color: red;
}
`]
    render() {
        return html`
<h1>Home</h1>
<p>
    Welcome to my website
</p>
`;
    }
}
```

Having a common component to inherit from may have other advantages. For instance to share some logic, although this might better be achieved via controllers.

This is all lit, but the same concept could be implemented with "bare" customElmements with relative ease.

Answer (score 0):

Define the variables in `:host` instead of `:root`, et voila!

```css
:host {
   --someGlobalVariable: 10px
}
```

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.root = this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } );
    const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet(),
    globalSheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
    sheet.replaceSync( css );
    globalSheet.replaceSync( globalCss );
    this.root.adoptedStyleSheets [ globalSheet, sheet ];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You do it via ::shadow pseudo-element. Like this:

```
::shadow .redColor
{
    background-color: red;    
}
```

That will apply styling to all elements inside shadow trees with .redColor class.

More info + other styling possibilities in this great article: [Shadow DOM 201](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/)

Comment: ::shadow was deprecated, Amid.

Comment: I know. But for now it works and is a viable solution among others mentioned in the article i referenced.

Comment: It will be completely removed, so I guess no one should be using it. The article is ok, of course.

Comment: Deprecation means time to get rid of it from projects. Browser vendors didn't do it to give you more time to be happy with old specs, but to give you time to drop it. Using deprecated specs in new projects is more than an anti pattern, if somebody did it in my team knowing it's deprecated, I would fire them the moment I notice that.

Comment: **::shadow is deprecated:** https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/remove-shadow-piercing