# angular-cli default style does not work

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Angular 2 with the CLI is not loading the default `styles.css`. Or maybe it is, but the styling does not work. I have to add styles in every component, which makes no sense.

For example, this works in my component css:

```
.qta-colors{    
  background-color: rgb( 5, 37, 65)
}
```

But if I move it to `styles.css` then it does not work.

Style is defined in `angular-cli.json`:

```
  "styles": [
     "styles.css" 
  ],
```

Comment: What encapsulation mode are you using?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#view-encapsulation

Comment: how do I addencapsulation: ViewEncapsulation?  where do I put it?

Comment: ... *"using the `encapsulation` property in the component metadata"*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use global css styles in shadow dom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694328/how-to-use-global-css-styles-in-shadow-dom)

Answer (score 0):

you can add your global css in index.html file like

```
 <style>
  .qta-colors{    
   background-color: rgb( 5, 37, 65)
  }   
  </style>
```

it will be accessible throughout you application