# How to apply external CSS to an external component within my angular component or using external CSS to the nested external component only

Tags: angular, shadow-dom, angular2viewencapsulation

I am a beginner, terminologies used here might be not properly applied.

My app has three components. One external component [clr-datagrid](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/datagrid) from [Project Clarity](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/get-started)

```
    <body>

    <app-root>

    <app-searchform> 
      <ss-multiselect-dropdown> 
        external library for making Dropdown Multiselect with bootstrap CSS 
     </ss-multiselect-dropdown>
   </app-searchform>

    <app-searchresult> 
        <clr-datagrid> external component for displaying result list </clr-datagrid>
   </app-searchresult>
       </app-root>

     </body>
```

In searchresult component,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchresult',
  templateUrl: './searchresult.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchresult.component.css',
    '../../../node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.css',
    '../../../node_modules/clarity-ui/clarity-ui.min.css'
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
```

The Problem is,

When I use ViewEncapsulation.**Emulated**, clarity-icons.min.css', clarity-ui.min.css are not applied to  nested component/ custom-element.

When I use ViewEncapsulation.**Native**, It works properly only in Chrome and Opera browsers. But Not in IE/ Firefox/ Safari.

When I use ViewEncapsulation.**None**,  works fine but CSS bleed out and affect searhform cmp styles.

What I have understood from online reading that the problem is about Shadow DOM, only Chrome support Shadow DOM, others not. I tried to use [webcomponents polyfill](https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills)

`<script src="../../../node_modules/webcomponents.js/webcomponents-hi-sd-ce.js"></script>` in index.html (may it was not the right way).

Could anyone plz help me that how can I apply clarity css and icons only to  component, and will not affect other parts of the app ?

Comment: A solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37355195/4600982

Comment: @Supersharp with ViewEncapsulation.Native, I tried your suggestion but did not work as expected. it loads the css in head tag but my shadow tree does not get styled. because styles get _ngcontent attribute but not my shadow elements.

Comment: the <style> element should be inserted in the shadow dom <template> directly.  I don't know how this can be done with Angular2 cause I'm not a specialist at all, sorry.