# css selector when using div parts

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to hide the contents of a div (desktoponly) on small screens, but i'm strugelling to apply the css from the stylesheet to the div.  I can oly assume this is because the div is nested under parts, as i am not very familiar with these. Perhaps i am using the wrong selector? Any help would be most appreciated.

HTML:

```
<template id="header-sidebar-template">
  <div part="base">
    <div part="content">
      <header part="header">
        <div id="desktoponly">
          <p>Hello world!</p>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
   #desktoponly { display: none; } }
```

RESULT:
Hello World! displays on all screen sizes (but I want it to be hidden below screen size 1000px)

Comment: The closing `}` for `@media (max-width: 1000px) {` is missing, is that error also in your real code?

Comment: _"HTML:"_ - that is all within a `template` element - so _that_ content won't get shown anywhere; some JavaScript must be cloning that template content somewhere, and inserting it into the document. Maybe in that process the element ID got modified or removed (to avoid duplicate IDs, if the same template was used to insert multiple elements) - so go inspect the actual element you see on your page, and check what ID that has.

Comment: Thanks at @CBroe . I have checked the element but and the ID does seem to be correct on the final output.... https://prnt.sc/Gir3dRMM_4zc

Comment: @CBroe good spot. Have updated the question with the closing }

Comment: That screenshot shows that you're dealing with a Shadow DOM there, so that is probably the reason your CSS does not apply in there. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37352637/1427878

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing `@media (max-width: 1000px) { #desktoponly { display: none; } }` do `@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { #desktoponly { display: none; } }` it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfotunately that doesn't fix it. Any styling I set is not applied so i think its something to do with the templates and div parts. I can use inline styling which does work ... but as far as im aware there is no way to apply @media rules with inline styling? Someone may be able to correct me on this.

Comment: @MattS in my case removing the template element in HTML and just keeping all the divs works fine

Comment: unfortunately i cant remove the template tags without breaking the site elsewhere. But i think this has narrowed down the issue - the probelm is with applying css to contents of a template. Probably warrants a seperate question.